# How to get registration from ICAO 24 bit code?

Tags: icao, aircraft-registration

The description of PlanePlotter claims that it can determine the registration letters from the ICAO 24 bit address algorithmically for some countries.

The only thing i got so far is how to get the country. Any clues?

**Edit:**

After some more research I found some information in the book "Principles of Avionics" by Albert Helfrick:

> Generally, there is no algorithm giving a one-to-one correspondence
>   between ICAO 24 bit addresses and the registration number of the
>   aircraft. Some ICAO member states did have an algorithm that would
>   translate ICAO 24 bit aircraft addresses to registration numbers but
>   ICAO strongly suggested the practice to stop.

Algorithm for swedish registrations: http://www.transportstyrelsen.se/publicdocuments/PDF165.pdf

Comment: Maybe some countries have a system and the people at PlanePlotter reverse engineered them?

Comment: Do you have a link to this claim?

Comment: http://www.coaa.co.uk/planeplotter.htm "PlanePlotter can can determine the registration letters algorithmically, from the 24-bit hex address"

Comment: Is there anyway to tell if the aircraft is rotary or fixed wing from the ICAO 24-bit address?

Comment: Hi @Chris: The edit in the question IMO should be an answer; feel free to submit it as an answer, self-answering is encouraged here. And personally I'd bold emphasize the "ICAO strongly suggested the practice to stop" part.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Apparently (according to [these folks](http://www.gatwickaviationsociety.org.uk/modeslookup.asp)) some countries use an algorithm to generate their ICAO (Mode S) 24-bit IDs. For those countries, you can simply reverse the algorithm and get a registration given the Mode S ID.

Others countries allow you to download their registration database, complete with the Mode S identifier ([you can get the US registration database here](http://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/aircraft_certification/aircraft_registry/releasable_aircraft_download/)) - it's a simple matter to load this into your own software and map the ICAO/Mode S ID code to a registration number.

As the folks at Gatwick Aviation Society have noted, some countries are tight-lipped about how their codes are assigned (and who they're assigned to), so these lookups are probably not complete.

Answer (score 1):

The Mode_S closed-group on Yahoo Groups has documented many of the allocation algorithms.

https://groups.yahoo.com/neo/groups/Mode_S/info

Apply to join and explain your motivations.  They have an extensive Files section.

Comment: There are no algorithms documented in the Files section of that group that I can find, only lists of <ICAO>,<algorithmically generated registration #>

Comment: Not only are there no algorithms in that Files listing, but the listing for Belgium is very incomplete and contains lots of tail codes that are not even allowed - all the ones starting with Q for example.

Answer (score 1):

Some countries use a deterministic formula (e.g. US, Japan, South Korea), others use do not. There are about a dozen or two that do have a formula. Take a look at the popular ADS-B decoder dump1090's [decoding logic](https://github.com/mutability/dump1090/blob/master/public_html/registrations.js).