# Does ADS-B signal contain the aircraft type?

Tags: ads-b

I am working on the construction of an atmospheric model that calculates GHG emissions from aviation transport in France, as input I need an aviation traffic report as well as information on the type of aircraft (e.g Airbus A380).
To get this information, I am going to 'build' an ADS-B ground station, but I am wondering if the aircraft type information is included in the ADS-B signal?

Comment: Why not use a source like ADSBexchange or OpenSky that already collects the data you need? No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: This page may be of some information: https://www.faa.gov/nextgen/equipadsb/capabilities/ins_outs/ but as @StephenS commented there are plenty of ADS-B sources out there.

Comment: Yeah really, reinventing that wheel would be like 95% of the project.

Comment: Related: [How to get registration from ICAO 24 bit code?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9440/3201). Would Eurocontrol [unique dataset for researchers of 12 million commercial flights](https://www.eurocontrol.int/news/new-eurocontrol-rnd-data-archive-launched) database help?

Comment: Is a question of budget, as the project is being leading by a startup with commercial objectives, so no way to apply for a research quotation.

Comment: @MigueL: "*no way to apply for a research quotation*", I don't know if you're answering my comment, if yes, then you may see this database if open data, released each quarter since several years.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the airplane type is not in the signal.  The identification contains the ICAO 24bit (Mode S) code.  You then need to map that to a registration which will have the type.  As mentioned in the comments, services like ADSBexchange and OpenSky attempt to do that mapping as part of their information processing.

So if you extracted ID 0x4840d6 from the message, you could do a [lookup](https://opensky-network.org/aircraft-profile?icao24=4840d6) to find it's registered in the Netherlands as a Fokker F70.